# How to resolve ambiguity in overloaded functions using SFINAE

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I have an incredibly exciting library that can translate points: it should work with any point types

```
template<class T>
auto translate_point(T &p, int x, int y) -> decltype(p.x, p.y, void())
{
    p.x += x;
    p.y += y;
}

template<class T>
auto translate_point(T &p, int x, int y) -> decltype(p[0], void())
{
    p[0] += x;
    p[1] += y;
}
```

`translate_point` will work with points that have public `x` and `y` members, and it will also work with tuples/indexable containers where `x` and `y` are represented by the first and second element, respectively.

The problem is, another library defines a point class with public `x` and `y`, but also allows indexing:

```
struct StupidPoint
{
    int x, y;

    int operator[](int i) const
    {
        if(i == 0) return x;
        else if(i == 1) return y;
        else throw "you're terrible";
    }

};
```

My application, using both libraries, is the following:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    StupidPoint stupid { 8, 3 };
    translate_point(stupid, 5, 2);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

but this makes GCC (and clang) unhappy:

```
error: call of overloaded ‘translate_point(StupidPoint&, int, int)’ is ambiguous
```

Now I can see why this is happening, but I want to know how to fix this (assuming I can't change the internals of StupidPoint), and, if there is no easy workaround, how I might as a library implementer make this easier to deal with.

Comment: Which one do you want to call in this case?

Comment: In this case, the first version since it's (at least in theory) a bit faster. 

Also, `operator[]` also has a non-const overload returning an `int&`, which I omitted in my simple test case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to give precedence to the case having public `x`/`y`, you can do this:

```
template<class T>
auto translate_point_impl(int, T &p, int x, int y) -> decltype(p.x, p.y, void())
{
    p.x += x;
    p.y += y;
}

template<class T>
auto translate_point_impl(char, T &p, int x, int y) -> decltype(p[0], void())
{
    p[0] += x;
    p[1] += y;
}

template<class T>
void translate_point(T &p, int x, int y) {
    translate_point_impl(0, p, x, y);
}
```

It goes without saying that the opposite configuration is given by switching the types of the first parameter.

---

If you have three or more options (says `N`), you can use a trick based on templates.
Here is the example above once switched to such a structure:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct choice: choice<N-1> {};

template<>
struct choice<0> {};

template<class T>
auto translate_point_impl(choice<1>, T &p, int x, int y) -> decltype(p.x, p.y, void()) {
    p.x += x; p.y += y;
}

template<class T>
auto translate_point_impl(choice<0>, T &p, int x, int y) -> decltype(p[0], void()) {
    p[0] += x;
    p[1] += y;
}

template<class T>
void translate_point(T &p, int x, int y) {
    // use choice<N> as first argument
    translate_point_impl(choice<1>{}, p, x, y);
}
```

As you can see, now `N` can assume any value.

Comment: this is actually very clever, but is there a way to make this work if you have 3 (or more) options to choose from?

Comment: I never saw this `decltype(void())` before, that is nice. It is weird to me though, it's "default constructing a void" here? It is nice that it works.

Comment: @jaymmer Yes, you can use a template class to resolve overloading. Do you want me to add an example to the answer?

Comment: that would be great, I'm not sure I know what you mean - you're talking about something different from what m.s. suggested?

Comment: @jaymmer Added a new section to the answer. Let me know if you have doubts.

Comment: +1 for the tag trick. This is a very interesting way of making intuitive overload resolution choices based on <0> <1> and so forth

Answer (score 8):

You could provide an overload for `StupidPoint`:

```
auto translate_point(StupidPoint &p, int x, int y)
{
    p.x += x;
    p.y += y;
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9f5e146399e3fdf)</kbd>

---

Another solution:

Since `operator[]` is const for `StupidPoint`, you can check this in your SFINAE condition:

```
template<class T>
auto translate_point(T &p, int x, int y) -> decltype(p[0] += 0, void())
{
    p[0] += x;
    p[1] += y;
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6e8d75fc4f3585c)</kbd>

---

You could also use a different type-traits based approach to select the appropriate `translate_point` function:

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_x_y : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_x_y<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().x, std::declval<T>().y, void())> : std::true_type { };

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_index : std::false_type { };

template<typename T>
struct has_index<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().operator[](0), void())> : std::true_type { };

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<has_x_y<T>::value> translate_point(T &p, int x, int y)
{
    p.x += x;
    p.y += y;
}

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<!has_x_y<T>::value && has_index<T>::value> translate_point(T &p, int x, int y)
{
    p[0] += x;
    p[1] += y;
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6655ee94b0b4c121)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

In this case, both of your overloads are under-constrained. You can't really call the second one with `StupidPoint`, but that isn't observable at the point of overload resolution. If you constrain both properly, you'll remove the ambiguity in this case:

```
template<class T>
auto translate_point(T &p, int x, int y) -> decltype(p.x += x, p.y += y, void()) { ... };

template<class T>
auto translate_point(T &p, int x, int y) -> decltype(p[1] += y, void()) { ... } // prefer checking 1, so you don't allow an operator[] that takes a pointer
```

Now, if `operator[]` returned an `int&` instead, this would still be ambiguous. In that case, you'd need a way to order the two overloads (maybe with an extra argument that is either `int` or `...`?), or simply disallow that case. That's a separate design decision.

Answer (score 1):

With SFINAE, I would do something like this:

```
template<class T, bool>
auto translate_point(T &p, int x, int y) -> decltype(p[0], void())
{
    p[0] += x;
    p[1] += y;
}

template<class T, bool = std::is_base_of<StupidPoint, T>::value>
auto translate_point(T &p, int x, int y) -> decltype(p.x, p.y, void())
{
    p.x += x;
    p.y += y;
}
```

By doing this, when T = (class with `StupidPoint` as base class), the second overload will be called.

But it is easier with a simple overload, as pointed out by *m.s.*