# Check if member function exists and is not inherited for SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

How can I check if a member function exists and is **not** inherited?

I need this to resolve ambiguity for the following example:

A type either has a `foo()` or a `bar()` member function. `Caller` will `call` the one that exists for the given type. However, `DerivedWithBar` inherits `foo()` from `BaseWithFoo` but defines its own `bar()`. Thus, `Caller` does not know which function to call.

I'd need a way to give the non-inherited `foo` precedence over the inherited `bar()`, but I do not know how to check if a member function is inherited or not.

```
#include <iostream>

struct BaseWithFoo
{
    template <typename T> void foo(T&&){std::cout << "Base::foo" << std::endl;}
};

struct DerivedWithBar : public BaseWithFoo
{
    template <typename T> void bar(T&&){std::cout << "DerivedWithBar::bar" << std::endl;}
};

struct DerivedWithFoo : public BaseWithFoo
{
    template <typename T> void foo(T&&){std::cout << "DerivedWithFoo::foo" << std::endl;}
};

struct EmptyDerived : public BaseWithFoo {};

struct BaseWithBar
{
    template <typename T> void bar(T&&){std::cout << "BaseWithBar::bar" << std::endl;}
};


struct Caller
{
    template <typename T>
    auto call(T&& x) -> decltype(x.foo(*this), void())
    {
        x.foo(*this);
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto call(T&& x) -> decltype(x.bar(*this), void())
    {
        x.bar(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
  Caller c;
  c.call(BaseWithFoo());
  c.call(DerivedWithFoo());
  c.call(DerivedWithBar());
  c.call(EmptyDerived());
  c.call(BaseWithBar());
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef116b8b971440df)</kbd>

**desired output:**

```
Base::foo
DerivedWithFoo::foo
DerivedWithBar::bar
Base::foo
BaseWithBar::bar
```

Comment: Do you know the signature of the function to test (`void U::foo(Caller&)`) ?

Comment: @Jarod42 the signature is as you wrote it, however it is a template function, so its needs to be generic

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to distinguish between inherited and non-inherited member functions by comparing types of member function pointers.

The following is a partial solution to my full problem ("giving non-inherited member functions precedence over inherited ones"). This will only call non-inherited `foo` or non-inherited `bar`.

```
struct Caller
{    
    template <typename T>
    auto call(T&& x) -> decltype(x.foo(*this),
        std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_same<
                decltype(&T::template foo<decltype(*this)>),
                void (T::*)(decltype(*this))
            >::value
        >())
    {
        x.foo(*this);
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto call(T&& x) -> decltype(x.bar(*this),
        std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_same<
                decltype(&T::template bar<decltype(*this)>),
                void (T::*)(decltype(*this))
            >::value
        >())
    {
        x.bar(*this);
    }
};
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14cb18a83444a2e2)</kbd>

Comment: You may add *priority* to solve the other part: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2e3e5512ef241c1).

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks, I was just typing something similar (based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38283990/678093)).

Answer (score 0):

With a bunch of template, we can get it as it follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

struct BaseWithFoo
{
    template <typename T> void foo(T&&){std::cout << "Base::foo" << std::endl;}
};

template<typename T>
struct DerivedWithBarT : public T
{
    template <typename U> void bar(U&&){std::cout << "DerivedWithBar::bar" << std::endl;}
};

using DerivedWithBar = DerivedWithBarT<BaseWithFoo>;

template<typename T>
struct DerivedWithFooT : public T
{
    template <typename U> void foo(U&&){std::cout << "DerivedWithFoo::foo" << std::endl;}
};

using DerivedWithFoo = DerivedWithFooT<BaseWithFoo>;

template<typename T>
struct EmptyDerivedT : public T {};

using EmptyDerived = EmptyDerivedT<BaseWithFoo>;

struct BaseWithBar
{
    template <typename T> void bar(T&&){std::cout << "BaseWithBar::bar" << std::endl;}
};

struct EmptyBase {};

template<typename...>
using void_t = void;

template<typename, typename = void_t<>>
struct HasFoo: std::false_type {};

template<typename T, template<typename> class U>
struct HasFoo<U<T>, void_t<decltype(&U<EmptyBase>::template foo<T>)>>: std::true_type {};

template<typename, typename = void_t<>>
struct HasBar: std::false_type {};

template<typename T, template<typename> class U>
struct HasBar<U<T>, void_t<decltype(&U<EmptyBase>::template bar<T>)>>: std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct BarOverFoo {
    static constexpr bool value = HasBar<T>::value && !HasFoo<T>::value;
};

template<typename T>
struct FooOverBar {
    static constexpr bool value = HasFoo<T>::value && !HasBar<T>::value;
};

template<typename T>
struct Both {
    static constexpr bool value = HasFoo<T>::value && HasBar<T>::value;
};

template<typename T>
struct None {
    static constexpr bool value = !HasFoo<T>::value && !HasBar<T>::value;
};

struct Caller
{
    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<FooOverBar<T>::value>
    call(T&& x)
    {
        x.foo(*this);
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<BarOverFoo<T>::value>
    call(T&& x)
    {
        x.bar(*this);
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<Both<T>::value>
    call(T&& x)
    {
        x.bar(*this);
    }

    template <typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<None<T>::value>
    call(T&& x)
    {
        callInternal(std::forward<T>(x));
    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    auto callInternal(T&& x) -> decltype(x.foo(*this), void())
    {
        x.foo(*this);
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto callInternal(T&& x) -> decltype(x.bar(*this), void())
    {
        x.bar(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Caller c;
    c.call(BaseWithFoo());
    c.call(DerivedWithFoo());
    c.call(DerivedWithBar());
    c.call(EmptyDerived());
    c.call(BaseWithBar());
}
```

Adjust the `call` methods according with your requirements.
I've set a few defaults I'm not sure are fine.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot expect the derived types to be templates