# Clang vs. GCC: Error in unevaluated context breaks SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, sfinae, clang++

While continuing work from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38347040/678093), I came across different behavior of clang and GCC.
I need to check the member function pointer because I need to know if the function is inherited or not.

When comparing member function pointers in an SFINAE context, member function `Foo::foo()` exists, but its body contains code (`x.hello()`) which eventually does not compile.

The following code compiles with clang.
GCC however seems to evaluate the function body of `Foo::foo()` and exits with an error (`'struct Caller' has no member named 'hello'`), despite being in an unevaluated SFINAE context (or so I hope).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo
{
    template <typename T> void foo(T&& x) { x.hello(); }
};

struct Caller
{    
    template <typename T>
    auto call(T&& x) -> decltype(
        std::enable_if_t<
            std::is_same<
                decltype(&T::template foo<decltype(*this)>),
                void (T::*)(decltype(*this))
            >::value
        >())
    {
        //x.foo(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
  Caller c;
  c.call(Foo());
}
```

I tested with:

- clang 3.8.0
- g++ 6.1.0

Compiler options for both: `-std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread`

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15f0f4fa3c2698fd)</kbd>

**My questions:**

1. who is right? Clang or GCC?
2. How can I get the code to compile with GCC?

Comment: How about mentioning the versions and options of the compilers? `x.hello()` is definitely not in a SFINAE context.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to the second question

> How can I get the code to compile with GCC?

I would simplify the expression being passed to the `decltype()`. If the compilation of the `call` method is dependent on the compilation of `x.foo(*this);`, then that is what you should use.

```
struct Foo
{
    template <typename T> void foo(T&& x) { x.hello(); }
};

struct Caller
{    
    template <typename T>
    auto call(T&& x, int) -> decltype(x.foo(*this))
    {
        //x.foo(*this);
    }
    template <typename T>
    void call(T&&, char){ std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
  Caller c;
  c.call(Foo(), 0);
}
```

[Demo here.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc8446c818022ca4)

---

I think the OP's issue with gcc lies in the address being taken of the function (or decaying to a function pointer if not explicitly taken). I think this is something of a corner case in the standard. The `x.hello()` would need to exist (compile) if the method `Foo::foo` is required; in general taking the address of something satisfies that, but in an unevaluated context (`decltype()`), I'm not sure if that would apply - certainly clang does not require it to exist (nor does MSVC).

In that respect,

> Who is right? Clang or GCC?

I suspect clang implements a more permissive reading of the standard and probably more correct reading. The operand to a `decltype()` is an unevaluated operand, see [[dcl.type.simple]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4);

> The operand of the decltype specifier is an unevaluated operand (Clause [expr]).

Comment: I need to check the member function pointer because I want to know if the function is inherited or not (see my [linked previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38347040/678093)).

Comment: @Niall I am struggling to understand why that works. `Caller` doesn't have a `hello` method. How can `void Foo::foo<Caller>(Caller&&)` be instantiated?

Comment: @JonathanMee. Correct, that is why the substitution fails, and then the method removed from the overload resolution. W.r.t the OP code, I think the issue lies in the address being taken of the function. I think this is something of a corner case in the standard. The `x.hello` would need to exist (compile) if the method is required; in general taking the address of something satisfies that, but in an unevaluated context (`decltype()`), I'm not sure if that would apply.

Comment: @Niall but if the taking the address requires `x.hello` to be compiled, and this fails, why isn't the char overload chosen here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6506b9f917f89623

Comment: @Niall So you're saying that `decltype` *doesn't* require the method to compile? (I mean that is how it's working on all the compilers, but my mind is a little blown by that.)

Comment: @m.s. At that point, it is a hard error - the address is deemed to be required (because of the `&`) by gcc; clang on the other hand seems to discard the required existence the pointer, so the error is not a hard one.

Comment: @JonathanMee. It would require the expression to compile, but since the substitution fails, the compiler doesn't require it to compile; the overload is removed (almost as if it was never there for the given set of arguments).

Comment: @Niall how could this "hard error" then be converted to a "SFINAE compatible error" in order to be able to compile with GCC? Besides that, I am of course still interested which compiler (if any) is reacting correctly.

Comment: @Niall Wait, wait, you say "since the substitution fails". What "substitution failure" are you talking about here? I'm seeing that the `int` version *is* being executed. That's what you're seeing too right? I've asked the question here if you would care to come clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38373768/2642059

Comment: @m.s. I can't find a simple workaround for gcc on this; even moving it to the template arguments results in an error; http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1579af7b02a144e4.

Comment: @JonathanMee. There were two conversation going on in my head, it is if there had been a substitution failure, e.g. if its was `decltype(x.foo1(*this))`. In the sample code above, the `int` variant is chosen.

Comment: @m.s. I think clang would be correct, I've update the answer as well.

Comment: I fail to see how your demo solves the problem of my question

Comment: I don't necessarily think it will, I'm sure your problem is larger than the MCVE examples you have posted; it is meant as further ideas and combining techniques. I have removed it. As for this question, I think clang's behaviour is most likely correct.

Comment: so is this a GCC bug I should report?

Comment: @m.s. I would think so, yes, it should be reported.

Comment: @m.s. Would changing your declaration of of `foo` solve your issue? For example: `template <typename T> decltype(declval<T>().hello(), void()) foo(T&& x) { x.hello(); }`

Comment: @JonathanMee No, unfortunately I cannot change `foo`

Comment: @m.s. Eureka, I've finally found a reason for `result_of`. It *does* require the method to compile. So you can use it instead of `decltype` and C++ will correctly select your overload function: `template <typename T> result_of_t<decltype(&T::foo)(T, Caller)> call(T&& x, int)`: http://ideone.com/1Ew89R

Comment: @Niall After reporting [this issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71879), I was told this is not a bug: "Taking the address of Foo::foo<Caller> instantiates it, which results in an error outside the immediate context, so you get an error not a substitution failure.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15261234/981959"

Comment: @m.s. I'm not too surprised, the address being taken is usually enough to require it to exist, but the `decltype` puts it in an unevaluted context, which is not really enough to require it to exist. If you filed the same issue with clang; that they compile the code when it shouldn't, you may receive the same response that it is not a bug. Interestingly enough, MSVC compiles the code as well. I mentioned this earlier, it is a corner case, I suspect the issue is that you don't want to depend on the outcome either way until (if at all) there is a definitive resolution.