# Should Taking the Address of a Templatized Function Trigger its Compilation?

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, function-pointers, addressof

I got an official answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373768/shouldnt-decltype-trigger-compilation-of-its-argument) that `decltype` should *not* trigger function compilation. In fact `decltype` on a function that is declared but not defined is legal.

Next question, should taking the address of a function trigger the compilation of a function? Take [this example](http://ideone.com/VuqmCJ):

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T&& x) { x.func(); }

int main()
{
    auto bar = &foo<int>;
}
```

All the compilers I've tested fail with an error like:

> Request for member `func` in `x`, which is of non-class type `int`

But if I just define `foo` and don't declare it, the code compiles fine. Can someone provide me with an official source on whether taking the address of a function should require it's compilation?

Comment: According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition%23One_Definition_Rule, "an object is odr-used if its address is taken", and "If an object or a function is odr-used, its definition must exist somewhere in the program; a violation of that is a link-time error". I don't have the relevant standard quotes to make this an answer

Comment: @KABoissonneault I'm OK with this. If you can cite http://en.cppreference.com for both of those quotes I'd consider that official enough.

Comment: @KABoissonneault It looks like [what you're citing](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/language/definition&diff=prev&oldid=73909) was written by [Cubbi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/273767/cubbi) I wish there was some way to hail him and get more information about it.

Comment: Best way to hail a wiki editor is to write something on their user page,  and the best way to clarify a wiki page is to write something on the discussion tab of that page. That sentence starts with "informally..." - I was trying to summarize the ODR in simple English because the standardese became way too thick (technically, taking an address is not odr use for unqualified pure virtuals, as noted a bit lower on the same page)

Comment: @KABoissonneault I've asked the obvious followup here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38437533/2642059

Answer (score 2):

3.2/2:

> An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated
>   operand (Clause 5) or a subexpression thereof. ... A non-overloaded 
>   function whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression or a
>   member of a set of candidate functions, if selected by overload
>   resolution when referred to from a potentially-evaluated expression,
>   is odr-used, unless it is a pure virtual function and its name is not
>   explicitly qualified.

Then 3.2/3:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
>   function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic
>   required. The definition can appear explicitly in the program, it can
>   be found in the standard or a user-defined library, or (when
>   appropriate) it is implicitly defined (see 12.1, 12.4 and
>   12.8). An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used.

The function name is definitely not an unevaluated operand (for example to `sizeof`, `decltype`), AND it appears in an expression, so it's potentially evaluated. Then the second one requires exactly one non-inline definition, or identical inline definitions in each translation unit.

Comment: This is the crux of your logic: "A non-overloaded function whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression... is odr-used" But I'm not seeing where taking the address of the function is evaluating it. For example `decltype(foo(int{ 13 }))` is not evaluating `foo`. Is `&foo<int>` evaluating it? I'm not certain from these quotes.

Comment: @Jonathan Mee The standard *explicitly states* that contexts like as an operand to `decltype` are not potentially evaluated but that in any other context when a name appears in an expression it is potentially-evaluated.

Comment: @JonathanMee Think of it this way, how could `bar` possibly work as a function pointer without having instantiated `foo<int>`? Also, this is the same circumstance where you get linker errors with things like `static const int = 4; int j; std::min(i, j)`

Comment: @MarkB http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition%23One_Definition_Rule which was [cited by KABoissonneault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402133/should-taking-the-address-of-a-templatized-function-trigger-its-compilation#comment64212686_38402133) concur with you: "an object is odr-used if its address is taken"

Comment: @Barry It's weird though. All the compilers I test allow me to take the address of functions which are declared but not defined. How does that work? I guess since I'm doing testing in a one .cpp file setup, declaring them in a .cpp allocates space for them?