# Determining the Parameter Types of an Undefined Function

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, decltype, function-parameter, addressof

I've recently learned that I cannot:

1. [Take the address of an undefined function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38437533/2642059)
2. [Take the address of a templatized function with a type it would fail to compile for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38402133/2642059)

But I've also recently learned that I *can* [call `decltype` to get the return type of said function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373768/shouldnt-decltype-trigger-compilation-of-its-argument)

So an undefined function:

```
int foo(char, short);
```

I'd like to know if there's a way that I can match the parameter types to the types in a `tuple`. This is obviously a meta programming question. What I'm really shooting for is something like `decltypeargs` in this example:

```
enable_if_t<is_same_v<tuple<char, short>, decltypeargs<foo>>, int> bar;
```

Can anyone help me understand how `decltypeargs` could be crafted?

Comment: @Barry That is in no way a duplicate of this question, all the answers require taking the address of my function, which I explicitly said I cannot do as it is undefined. Please reopen.

Comment: Doubt it. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah I doubt it too. I don't actually care about undefined functions. But it would be really helpful to me to be able to get the function signature of a templatetized function that wouldn't survive SFINAE.

Comment: @Barry I did, all of them. And I tried them. They're the reason that I've started doubting this is possible. I don't think there is a way to pass an undefined function as an argument. Thus I have begun to think of this as impossible.

Comment: @Barry: What does `&T::operator()` do then?

Comment: Maybe the `decltype` makes it okay? Cos unevaluated context. OP's tests seem to suggest otherwise though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `foo` isn't a function object, it's a function - that specialization isn't used.

Comment: @Barry: Now you're talking. Perhaps be more clear next time instead of just "did you even read them?" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For non-overloaded functions, pointers to functions, and pointers to member functions, simply doing `decltype(function)` gives you the type of the function in an unevaluated context, and that type contains all the arguments.

So to get the the argument types as a tuple, all you need are a lot of specializations:

```
// primary for function objects
template <class T>
struct function_args
: function_args<decltype(&T::operator()>
{ };

// normal function
template <class R, class... Args>
struct function_args<R(Args...)> {
    using type = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

// pointer to non-cv-qualified, non-ref-qualified, non-variadic member function
template <class R, class C, class... Args>
struct function_args<R (C::*)(Args...)>
: function_args<R(Args...)>
{ };

// + a few dozen more in C++14
// + a few dozen more on top of that with noexcept being part of the type system in C++17
```

With that:

```
template <class T>
using decltypeargs = typename function_args<T>::type;
```

This requires you to write `decltypeargs<decltype(foo)>`.

---

With C++17, we will have `template <auto>`, so the above can be:

```
template <auto F>
using decltypeargs = typename function_args<decltype(F)>::type;
```

and you'd get the `decltypeargs<foo>` syntax.

Comment: Wow my mind is blown. I didn't have any idea about the `decltype` thing. I was actually writing an answer about how it couldn't be done. +1 Also, I've never seen an `auto` as a template type specifier. Does that just do perfect forwarding?

Comment: @JonathanMee http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r2.html

Comment: Might this be a good time to use `typename` rather than `class`? Since you're not passing classes. They're functionally equivalent but readability is important.

Comment: So after trying to work through this for my clarification I have a couple questions: 1) You say "+ a few dozen more in C++14" that pertains only to methods, right? I think your "normal function" definition does everything I need 2) Only the specializations of `function_args` are ever used. Did you choose to define it this way so you could use the specializations to templatize what was being passed in?

Comment: @JonathanMee 1) member functions. 2) The specializations let you pull apart the types, to get out the parts that you need.

Comment: @Barry I've asked enough questions here. I'll accept this once the paint finishes drying on the answer. But I do have one more follow up question, which I've posted separately here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38463980/2642059