# Pull Apart Function Type With Specialized Function

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-function, template-classes

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38457112/2642059) picks apart a function type using a class template:

```
template <typename T>
struct function_args {};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_args<R(Args...)> {
    using type = tuple<Args...>;
};

template <typename T>
using decltypeargs = typename function_args<T>::type;
```

As I studied what was being done here I tried to rewrite `function_args`. I attempted to do this using a function so as to eliminate the need for the `decltypeargs` template. But found myself mired in improper syntax:

```
template <typename T>
tuple<> myTry();

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
tuple<Args...> myTry<Ret(Args...)>();
```

My hope had been to call `decltype(myTry<decltype(foo)>())` to get the `tuple` type instead of having to call `decltypeargs<decltype(foo)>`. Is there a way to do this with a function declaration?

Comment: You can't do partial specialization with function template. But I think you want to ask something else. Not very clear to me.

Comment: @Arunmu Sounds like you've answered my question. But I'm not certain how to improve the wording. I'm trying to pull a function's return and arguments apart, and I need to use specialization to do that. I wanted to do it with a function, but it sounds like I can't. Is that any clearer?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. `myTry()` is just more typing than not using it - what's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @JonathanMee Yes, better, but I am afraid that the answer remains the same :)

Comment: @Barry I was just trying to rewrite your answer in terms that made more sense to me (function declarations.) But it seems that function declarations cannot be specialized like this. So I just need to get more comfortable with specializing objects.

Comment: @Barry You feel like calling that guy brilliant is a bit too far? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//------------------------ Machinery:
#include <tuple>

template< class Ret, class... Args >
std::tuple<Args...> m( Ret(Args...) );

//------------------------- Example:
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

void foo( double );

using namespace std;
auto main()
    -> int
{
    using Args_tuple = decltype( m( foo ) );
    cout << typeid( Args_tuple ).name() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Ugh. That's exactly what I couldn't put together how to do, right there in one function. Who needs specialization when you can do it right the first time?

Comment: I've asked a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38482805/2642059 I think I must not have a good grip on how `decltype(m(foo))` is working cause I can't expand it to work with methods.

Answer (score 3):

With a function, you can either just reuse the same type trait from before:

```
template <typename T>
function_args<T> myTry();
```

Or you can reimplement the same with functions. You can't partially specialize function templates, but you can overload:

```
namespace detail {
    template <class T> struct tag { };

    template <class R, class... Args>
    tag<std::tuple<R, Args...>> myTry(tag<R(Args...)> );

    template <class R, class C, class... Args>
    tag<std::tuple<R, Args...>> myTry(tag<R(C::*)(Args...)> );        

    // etc.
}

template <typename T>
auto myTry() { return detail::myTry(detail::tag<T>{}); }
```

Comment: What's the `tag` for?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That's what he's using to hack in partial specialization. Fundamentally this is my bad question, obviously the right answer is just use the struct, this is just  a creative workaround.

Comment: The 2 definitions of `myTry` would be different overloads without `tag`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes, but the interest from the linked question is in extracting the argument types. `tag` allows us to do that within the context of a functions parameters. If you can think of a better way to do that within a function, I'd say you've come up with a better solution and should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Functions cannot be specialized like that, but you don't need to specialize a function for this. Tested with gcc 6.1.1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename T> struct my_try;

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct my_try<Ret(Args...)> {

    std::tuple<Args...> operator()();

};

template<typename T>
auto MyTry()
{
    return my_try<T>()();
}


void foo(int, char);

int main()
{
    decltype(MyTry<decltype(foo)>()) t;

    int *a= &std::get<0>(t);
    char *b= &std::get<1>(t);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haha, I suppose that does accomplish it in a function. I was hoping to *replace* the struct with a function though. [It sounds as though that's not possible though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463980/pull-apart-function-type-with-specialized-function#comment64332056_38463980). Maybe instead of this you could just quote something official sounding that specifies that functions cannot be specialized?

Comment: I don't see what there is to gain from replacing the struct. It takes up exactly 0 bits, once it's compiled.

Comment: You're completely right. I just felt more comfortable with function declarations, so I was trying to use them. So the answer, is simply: "You can't do that." But it would be nice if we could get a quote in here citing something other than "Because I said so."

Comment: @JonathanMee: Functions can be completely specialized, but not partially specialized.

Comment: It's difficult to provide a quote from the Standard for this, because it does not really say anywhere that function templates cannot be partially specialized; it just doesn't say that they *can* be (whereas it has subsection 14.5.5 specifically devoted to class template partial specialization, this is distinct from subsection 14.7.3 and section 14.8 which talk about explicit template specialization).