# Can I Write Relational Operators in Terms of Arithmetic Operations?

Tags: c++, templates, math, functor, relational-operators

So I have a fairly complex function:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const int param1, const int param2, int& out_param)
```

Given `int bar`, `const int arg1`, and `const int arg2` the function will be called with either: `foo<plus<int>>(arg1, arg2, bar)` or `foo<minus<int>>(arg1, arg2, bar)`

Internally the function is rather complex but I am doing different relational operators based on the type of functor that was passed as a template parameter.

In the case of `plus` I need to do:

1. `arg1 > arg2`
2. `bar > 0`
3. `bar > -10`

In the case of `minus` I need to do:

1. `arg1 < arg2`
2. `bar < 0`
3. `bar < 10`

Note that `10` does not have the same sign in both **3**s. I am currently solving all this by passing a second template parameter (`less` or `greater`.) But I was thinking it might make more sense to write these relations as arithmetic operations. Is that even possible, or do I need to take the second template parameter?

Comment: `foo<plus>` and `foo<minus>` can be trampoline functions that call into more complicated template machinery where you can encode the `less` `greater` and the appropriate constants.

Comment: @AndyG Yeah, I suppose I could do a `constexpr if` based on the type.

Comment: Basically that's the way to go. Will probably be cleaner than without `constexpr if`. I think you've got the gist of it, would you like a code example, too? Is there another way you're hoping for this to work?

Comment: @AndyG Yeah I guess if that's as good as we got and you write it up I'll accept. But what I was thinking of was a way to magic less than out of `minus` and greater than out of `plus`.

Comment: There's no inherent binding of `less` to `minus` or `greater` to `plus`, so the traditional way would be through traits, but that is a lot of extra machinery that you just don't need when `if constexpr` is around

Comment: How are you passing `std::plus<int>{}` to `auto T`? `std::plus` is not an integral type

Comment: @AndyG Yeah `T` can be anything. I learned about `auto` template parameters here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38457112/2642059 And I've found them extremely useful for handing around functors/function pointers/member pointers. I'm effectively passing the type *and* the object in one parameter there.

Comment: Can you show a compiling example where you pass `std::plus<int>{}` as an explicit template argument for a function?

Comment: @AndyG And of course you're totally right T.T I can't pass a functor as a template argument :( I thought this was possible. I'll be asking a follow up question and post it here.

Comment: @AndyG I've asked a question for clarification on what is and isn't allowed as an argument to an `auto` template parameter here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53761899/2642059 Just thought I'd link in case you would like to weigh in.

Comment: @JonathanMee [tag:C++20] with `operator<=>` permits non-type template parameters of (some) class types.  I'm uncertain if lambdas or `std::plus` will be one of them, but as both are monostate types there is no reason why they won't.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Sadly, the standard functors do not define relational operators, so I think even in C++20, I won't be able to do this. Thank you for the tip though. I also found this rather exciting tidbit in my linked question, and I've been excited about it ever since.

Comment: @jona adding `<=> = default` to std types is probably worth proposing.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It is at that. I'd love to... though I've never written a proposal. I don't suppose there's a beginner's guide somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
T{}(0, arg1) > T{}(0,arg2);
T{}(0, bar) > 0;
T{}(0, bar) > -10;
```

The basic idea is `a > b` if and only if `-a < -b`.  And `plus(0,a)==a` while `minus(0,a)==-a`.

The last one is tricky, as we want to change the order of `<` and the sign.  Luckily they cancel:

Suppose we want a constant that is `-10` in the plus case, and `10` in the minus case.  Then

```
plus(0,-10)
```

is `-10` and

```
minus(0,-10)
```

is `10`.

So we get:

```
T{}(0, bar) > T{}(0, T{}(0,-10))
```

in the plus case, the rhs is `0+0+-10`, aka `-10`.

In the minus case, this is `0-(0-(-10))`, aka `-10`.

So the short form is:

```
T{}(0,bar) > -10
```

and it should work.

Comment: Oh snap, that's sexy.

Answer (score 1):

Besides [@Yakk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53750639/27678) there are a number of ways you can do this. Here are 5.

#### Method 1: Function traits

This is more of a classic technique used before more advanced template-metaprogramming techniques became available. It's still quite handy. We specialize some structure depending on `T` to give us the types and constants we want to use.

```
template<class T>
struct FooTraits;

template<class T>
struct FooTraits<std::plus<T>>
{
    using Compare = std::greater<T>;
    static constexpr std::tuple<int, int> barVals{0, 10};
};

template<class T>
struct FooTraits<std::minus<T>>
{
    using Compare = std::less<T>;
    static constexpr std::tuple<int, int> barVals{0, -10};
};

template <class T>
void foo(const int arg1, const int arg2, int& bar)
{
    using traits = FooTraits<T>;
    typename traits::Compare cmp{};
    cmp(arg1, arg2);
    cmp(bar, std::get<0>(traits::barVals));
    cmp(bar, std::get<1>(traits::barVals));
}
```

### [Live Demo 1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/auzkKK9LgzQg5CGF)

---

#### Method 2: Full specialization

Another "classic" technique that remains useful. You are probably familiar with this technique, but I'm showing it for completeness. So long as you never need to *partially* specialize a function, you can write different version of it for the types you need:

```
template <class T>
void foo(const int arg1, const int arg2, int& bar);

template <>
void foo<std::plus<int>>(const int arg1, const int arg2, int& bar)
{
    arg1 > arg2;
    bar > 0;
    bar > 10;
}

template <>
void foo<std::minus<int>>(const int arg1, const int arg2, int& bar)
{
    arg1 < arg2;
    bar < 0;
    bar < -10;
}
```

### [Live Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nmX51TygQqszmzGe)

---

#### Method 3: Tagged dispatch

A third classic technique that turns a type check into an overloading problem. The gist is that we define some lightweight `tag` struct that we can instantiate, and then use that as a differentiator between overloads. Often this is nice to use when you have a templated class function, and you don't want to specialize the entire class just to specialize said function.

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class...> struct tag{};

    void foo(const int arg1, const int arg2, int& bar, tag<std::plus<int>>)
    {
        arg1 > arg2;
        bar > 0;
        bar > 10;
    }

    void foo(const int arg1, const int arg2, int& bar, tag<std::minus<int>>)
    {
        arg1 < arg2;
        bar < 0;
        bar < -10;
    }
}
template <class T>
void foo(const int arg1, const int arg2, int& bar)
{
    return detail::foo(arg1, arg2, bar, detail::tag<T>{});
}
```

### [Live Demo 3](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bQPkqY5b7NX9cvrQ)

---

#### Method 4: Straightforward `constexpr if`

Since C++17 we can use `if constexpr` blocks to make a compile-time check on a type. These are useful because if the check fails *the compiler doesn't compile that block at all*. This oftentimes leads to much easier code than before, where we had to use complicated indirection to classes or functions with advanced metaprogramming:

```
template <class T>
void foo(const int arg1, const int arg2, int& bar)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::plus<int>>)
    {
        arg1 > arg2;
        bar > 0;
        bar > 10;
    }
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::minus<int>>)
    {
        arg1 < arg2;
        bar < 0;
        bar < -10;
    }
}
```

### [Live Demo 4](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bQPkqY5b7NX9cvrQ)

---

#### Method 5: `constexpr` + trampolining

*trampolining* is a metaprogramming technique where you use a "trampoline" function as an intermediary between the caller and the actual function you wish to dispatch to. Here we will use it to map to the appropriate comparison type (`std::greater` or `std::less`) as well as the integral constants we wish to compare `bar` to. It's a little more flexible than Method 4. It also separates concerns a bit, too. At the cost of readability:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<class Cmp, int first, int second>
    void foo(const int arg1, const int arg2, int& bar)
    {
        Cmp cmp{};
        cmp(arg1, arg2);
        cmp(bar, first);
        cmp(bar, second);
    }
}

template <class T>
void foo(const int arg1, const int arg2, int& bar)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::plus<int>>)
        return detail::foo<std::greater<int>, 0, 10>(arg1, arg2, bar);
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::minus<int>>)
        return detail::foo<std::less<int>, 0, -10>(arg1, arg2, bar);
}
```

### [Live Demo 5](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bjc3poGN7RtJk4vr)

Comment: Just wanted to say that I appreciated all the effort that went into this. I'm restricted to Visual Studio 2012 for this project so, I think you're only suggestion that I could benefit from was the specialization. Ultimately I found that passing 2 template arguments was just the best approach for this problem. But I find these very educational in a more general sense as well. So thank you.

Comment: @JonathanMee: I'm sorry about your luck. That's coming from a former VS2012 user. I hope you get to upgrade soon, the product has really improved through VS 2017. That said, I think with some fiddling we could make the function traits and the tagged dispatch approaches work there, but full specialization is probably good enough.