# Are There Restrictions on What can be Passed to auto Template Parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, c++17, auto

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) we got [`auto` template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto). I was trying to use one to pass an object in this question: [Can I Write Relational Operators in Terms of Arithmetic Operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53750460/2642059) But directed by [AndyG's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750460/can-i-write-relational-operators-in-terms-of-arithmetic-operations#comment94355169_53750460) I found that didn't compile :(

Given the template function:

```
template <auto T>
void foo()
```

There seem to be restrictions on what I can pass as a template parameter. For example, as seen in my linked question I cannot seem to pass functors:

```
foo<plus<int>{}>()
```

Is there a list somewhere of what is and isn't allowed?

Comment: The same restrictions as without `auto` apply: https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/5687540/non-type-template-parameters Also see the comments to the top answer with regard to changes in upcoming C++20.

Comment: @AndyG I mean I'm worthless without auto-complete :J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++17, the restriction can be found in [[temp.param]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#4):

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - `std​::​nullptr_­t`, or
> - a type that contains a placeholder type.

with additional restrictions on the arguments in [[temp.arg.nontype]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#2):

> For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - a subobject,
> - a temporary object,
> - a string literal,
> - the result of a `typeid` expression, or
> - a predefined `_­_­func_­_`­ variable.

Where you're going wrong is that `std::plus<int>` is not a valid non-type template parameter. It is none of those things in that first list.

---

In C++20, the kinds of types you can use as non-type template parameters will be greatly expanded. We will be able to use class types as non-type template parameters, provided those class types satisfy something called "strong structural equality." In the current draft, that is defined in terms of public, defaulted `operator<=>`. In P1185, currently in flight and likely to be adopted, it will change slightly to be defined in terms of public, defaulted `operator==`.

But even in C++20, `std::plus<int>` does not actually define any comparison operators - so you still would not be able to use it as a non-type template parameter.

Comment: So just checking here, but isn't `operator==` defined by default? Meaning, I think that, after C++20 `plus<int>` *would* be allowed, right?

Comment: @JonathanMee No, it's not.

Comment: Oh curses, yeah, it's assignment that's defined by default :(

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is entirely handled by the following standard statement:

> [[temp.arg.nontype]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype)
>   [1:](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#1)
>    If the type T of a template-parameter ([temp.param]) contains a placeholder type ([dcl.spec.auto]) or a placeholder for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct]), the type of the parameter is the type deduced for the variable x in the invented declaration
>
> ```
> T x = template-argument ;
> ```
>
> If a deduced parameter type is not permitted for a template-parameter declaration ([temp.param]), the program is ill-formed.

Passing functor types is allowed. Passing a functor instance is not, just like passing an instance of `struct A {};` is not.

As for what non-type template parameters are allowed:

> [4:](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#4) 
>   A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualified) types:
>
> (4.1)
>       a type that is literal, has strong structural equality ([class.compare.default]), has no mutable or volatile subobjects, and in which if there is a defaulted member operator<=>, then it is declared public,
>
> (4.2)
>       an lvalue reference type,
>
> (4.3)
>       a type that contains a placeholder type ([dcl.spec.auto]), or
>
> (4.4)
>       a placeholder for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct]).
>
> [5:](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#5) 
>   [ Note: Other types are disallowed either explicitly below or implicitly by the rules governing the form of template-arguments ([temp.arg]).
>   — end note
>    ]
>   The top-level cv-qualifiers on the template-parameter are ignored when determining its type.

Comment: So... is there a list somewhere of what "is not permitted for a template-parameter declaration?" I guess that's the answer to my question.